# How to make a forward declaration for private method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, forward-declaration

I'm arranging my methods into groups using #pragma mark in implementation. But sometimes, the method implementation code appears below the code that calls this method, and I'm getting "Instance method not found" warnings. It happens when I'm using private methods. How to fix that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplest method is to use a anonymous category. Add something like this to the top of your `.m` file, before your `@implementation`:

```
@interface MyClass()
- (void)myPrivateMethod;
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you would use a class extension inside of your implementation file to define these methods.  In this manner, your 'public' API is still defined in your header file, and your implementation file contains the definition of your pseudo-private methods.

YourClass.m

```
@interface MyClass()

- (void)myPrivateMethod;

@end


@implementation MyClass

- (void)myPublicMethod
{
    // This will not throw an error or warning
    [self myPrivateMethod];
} 

- (void)myPrivateMethod
{
    // Do something
}

@end
```

Comment: The disadvantage of using a named category is that you need a corresponding `@implementation MyClass(PrivateMethods)`, otherwise you'd get a warning. Just use an anonymous category.

Comment: The preferred syntax for a private class extension is `@interface MyClass()`.

Answer (score 1):

In your Class.m implementation file, you can add an interface section at the beginning and declare private functions in there:

```
@interface YourClassName (private)

-(void)aPrivateMethod:(NSString*)aParameter;
...

@end

@implementation YourClassName
...
@end
```